# Express.js CRUD application bug: update function does wrong redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**UPDATE:**

Matus Dubrava, you are right, of cores, but I changed that line to `res.redirect('/post/show/' + pid);` and it still does not work. The route is `http://localhost:3000/post/edit/5d0fddd730d83f0c32c1e0ca`

The snippet responsible with showing an individual post does work. It is:

```
app.get('/post/show/:id', function(req, res){
    Post.findById(req.params.id, function(err, post){
        res.render('single_post.pug', {
            post: post
        });
    });
});
```

Yet, redirecting with `res.redirect('/post/show/' + pid);` does not work.

I am working on a basic CRUD application with **Node**, **MongoDB** and **Express**. I use Jade for the views ad Bootstrap 4 for styling.

There is an edit post functionality that works ok, but my update has a bug I have not been able to spot and fix:

The edit form view:

```
h2 #{title}

form(action="/post/edit/" + post._id, method="POST")
    .form-group
        input.form-control(type="hidden", name="post_id", value=post.post_id)
    .form-group
        input.form-control(type="text", name="title", placeholder="Post title" value=post.title)
    .form-group
        input.form-control(type="text", name="category", placeholder="Post category" value=post.category)
    .form-group
        textarea.form-control(rows="5", name="body")= post.body
    .form-group
        input.btn.btn-sm.btn-block.btn-primary(type="submit", value="Update")
```

The code corresponding to **edit** and **update** actions:

```
// Edit post
app.get('/post/edit/:id', function(req, res){
    Post.findById(req.params.id, function(err, post){
        res.render('edit_post.pug', {
            post: post
        });
    });
});


// Update post
app.post('/post/edit/:id', function(req, res){
    let post = {};
    post.pid = req.body.post_id;
    post.title = req.body.title;
    post.category = req.body.category;
    post.body = req.body.body;

    let query = {_id:req.params.id}

    Post.update(query, post, function(err){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        } else {
            res.redirect('/post/show/' + pid);
        }
    });
});
```

The post *does* get updated but:

1. The redirect url is `http://localhost:3000/post/show/:pid`;
2. The browser shows `Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`.

Where is my mistake?

**PS:** I can't add all the code here so I have put together **[this](https://pastebin.com/CzXGcnz1)** paste-bin.

Comment: I guess you need to send array or object containing "title" too while redirecting to that route, as while rendering to that route , the  object/array from which the title is being destructed or extracted seems undefined or null

Comment: @RishabhJain How would you code that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised you're getting as far as you are without an error. The error suggests you are not able to successfully retrieve the `post` object when rendering the '/post/show/:id' route. Based on your code snippets, it looks like you're not passing the correct post id in your redirect URL.

You can reference your post id in a few ways (e.g. `req.body.post_id`, `post.pid`, or `req.params.id`), but your using `pid`:

`res.redirect('/post/show/' + pid);`

`pid` is not defined. Try updating your update code to the following:

```
// Update post
app.post('/post/edit/:id', function(req, res){
    let post = {};
    post.pid = req.body.post_id;
    post.title = req.body.title;
    post.category = req.body.category;
    post.body = req.body.body;

    let query = {_id:req.params.id}

    Post.update(query, post, function(err){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        } else {
            res.redirect('/post/show/' + req.params.id);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: We are not seeing everything here, it has to be defined since the resulting url is `http://localhost:3000/post/edit/5d0fddd730d83f0c32c1e0ca` so the `pid` is `5d0fddd730d83f0c32c1e0ca`, not undefined. Problem is in incorrect `show`/`edit` part of path.

Comment: Of corse. There is no `pid`. Using `res.redirect('/post/show/' + req.params.id);`. (While `res.redirect('/post/show/' + post.pid);` failed).

Answer (score 3):

When you are calling redirect, this `/post/show/:pid` is just a normal string which you can also see from the url that you are being redirected to - `http://localhost:3000/post/show/:pid` (see the last part of it). Or in other words `:pid` in the string is not being replaced automatically, unlike in case of `get` or `post` methods of `app` which are performing this replacement internally.

You can simply build the string yourself

```
url = "/post/show/" + pid;
res.redirect(url);
```

Comment: I tried it. it did not work. Please note that the update _does_ take place.

Comment: And after you have made the change, what is the url that you are being redirected to?

Comment: So the url works now. Check the object that you are retrieving in `get` method. I have a strong feeling that it is being updated incorrectly, otherwise the `title` property would exist. Or your `pid` is not equal to `id` based on which you are fetching entries from DB.

Comment: It... kinda works. It should be `http://localhost:3000/post/show/5d0fddd730d83f0c32c1e0ca`, *not* `http://localhost:3000/post/edit/5d0fddd730d83f0c32c1e0ca`.

Comment: It is rather hard to believe that the above code is redirecting you to `edit` when clearly the redirect string is correct. You should checks whether you are hitting the right endpoint and if so, then you should check whether you are not being redirect multiple times due to code in function bound to `/post/show/:pid` path

Comment: You are right, of cores, but I changed that line to `res.redirect('/post/show/' + pid);` and it still does not work. The route is `http://localhost:3000/post/edit/5d0fddd730d83f0c32c1e0ca`. I have added more info to the question.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me and your code looks ok. Can you create Github repo with all of the project files so that I can debug it locally?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no handler for `/post/show/:pid` or you have not shown the complete code. This either means either once the update is done then you need to go back to the edit page again. If that is the case then you need to change your code line from

```js
res.redirect('/post/show/:pid');
```

to

```js
res.redirect('/post/edit/' + pid);
```

Comment: Yes you are right and the mistake should have been obvious to me. I corrected it but the redirect still does not work. I have added more info to the question.